# read_xlsxのpathをstr_cで作成するとファイルが存在しないエラーが起こる

Tags: r, tidyverse

ファイル保存のパスの冒頭をstringr::str_cで作成します。

```
DirectoryName <- "D1"
SavePath <- str_c("data/ディレクトリ/", DirectoryName, sep = "", collapse = NULL)
```

このSavePathを用いてreadxl::read_xlsxでエクセルファイルを開こうとするとエラーになります。

```
read_xlsx(str_c(SavePath, "TargetExcel.xlsx", sep = "", collapse = NULL ), sheet = "sheet_name")
```

エラーメッセージは

```
 エラー: Evaluation error:  zip ファイル 'data/ｺ蟷ｹ繧ｷ繧ｹ繝・Β202001.xlsx' を開くことができません
```

です。

これについて、str_cをbase::paste0にするとエクセルを正常に開けます。ファイルパスには日本語を含みます。

str_cで開けず、paste0で開ける理由がおわかりになれば教えてください。

Comment: この辺の記事を追っていくと何とかなるかも。[第14章 Rにおける文字コード*](https://shohei-doi.github.io/quant_polisci/encoding-r.html), [{stringr}/{stringi}とbaseの文字列処理について](https://rpubs.com/yamano357/92478), [stringiとWindowsと文字コードとかそのへんのメモ](https://yutannihilation.github.io/Rmd/stringi_encode.html)

Answer (score 3):

質問者です。
SavePath自体の文字コードがR上ではUTF-8で処理されていて、ここにshift-jisが混じるとパスが内部で文字化けを起こしてエラーを出しているようでした。
解決策としてはiconvを使ってutf-8からshift-jisに変換したパスを使う、というものになります。

```
DirectoryName <- "D1"
SavePath <- str_c("data/ディレクトリ/", DirectoryName, sep = "", collapse = NULL)
SavePath <- iconv(SavePath, from = "utf-8", to = "cp932")
```

として、

```
read_xlsx(
    iconv(
        str_c(SavePath, "TargetExcel.xlsx", sep = "", collapse = NULL ),
        from = "uft-8", to = "cp932")
    ),
    sheet = "sheet_name")
```

とすると解決しました。
おそらくwindows上でRを使っているのが原因だと考えられます。
最後のsheet_name部分も文字コードが混在すると化けることがありますので、こちらも場合によってはshift-jisに変換しなければなりません。
paste0はこのあたりを曖昧に解決してくれるが、stringr::str_cは厳格にutf-8を使うようにできていて、このような現象が起きたのだと推察します。

コメント、ありがとうございました。

Comment: 質問時とは別アカウントを作成してしまっているようです。ヘルプを参考にアカウントのマージを検討してください。 - [間違えてアカウントを 2 件作成してしまいました。どうしたらマージできますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: ありがとうございます。マージしました。